# Display data from another model in admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

How to display in `OrderAdmin`: `Basket` owner, products, quantity of products?

I try Inline:

admin.py:

```
class BasketInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Basket

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BasketInline,
    ]
admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

but it does not work.

```
class Basket(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_basket', verbose_name='Owner')
    name = models.CharField("Basket_Name", max_length=30)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='BasketProduct', blank=True, null=True)


class BasketProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    basket = models.ForeignKey('Basket')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    desc = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class ShippingOptions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Order(models.Model):
    bask = models.OneToOneField(Basket)
    shipp = models.OneToOneField(ShippingOptions)
```

Maybe I need a different way. Please any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need foreignKey on `Order` in you `Basket` model:

```
class Basket(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_basket', verbose_name='Owner')
    name = models.CharField("Basket_Name", max_length=30)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='BasketProduct', blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, blank=True, verbose_name='Owner')
```

or you have error in first model row:

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, related_name='user_basket', verbose_name='Owner')
```